# SQLite - SELECT query returning more than expected

Tags: sql, sqlite

In the following my SQLite database has 10 values in each table.  However, when performing my query there are around 100 results returned.

```
 SELECT videoformat, audioformat FROM videocodec, audiocodec
```

Any ideas with why it is doing this?

Thanks

Comment: How many rows did you want to get back? 10? You probably need to join the tables on a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL says: for each row in videocodec, select all rows in audiocodec.  That will give 10x10 or 100 rows.  It's equivalent to:

```
select  *
from    videocodec
cross join
        audiocodec
```

You probably mean to retrieve both audio and video codecs.  You can do that with a union:

```
select  codecname
from    videocodec
union
select  codecname
from    audiocodec
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting back all combinations of rows from both tables, also known as the Cartesian product. 10 x 10 = 100.